# How to initialize class member array with 0

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I have the next class and want to initialize _operators array with 0:

```
    //Entity.h
class Entity
{
    static const unsigned short operatorTypeColumn = 1;
    static const unsigned short outputValueColumn = 4;
private:
    mainDataType _operators[operatorsMaxCount][operatorsTableWidth];
    }

    //Entity.cpp.          I thought this should work in C++ v11
Entity::Entity(void) : _operators[operatorsMaxCount][operatorsTableWidth]
{

}
```

I thought this sold work in C++ v11 but i got error... how can i initialize array with 0.. with ugly for? i don't want make it static

Comment: You forgot the trailing `()` on your array initializer, and you don't need the dimensions there; only in the decl. I.e. ` : _operator()`. sidenote: terrible name for a member var.

Comment: why is it terrible (in that array there are values of operators +, -, /) etc?

Comment: In a language that is often *littered* with the word `operator`, you can surely call it something else (`op` springs to my mind).

Comment: It makes senth.. there is probability of conflict but i care more abaut logic and objective clearness than abaut potential conflict... I don't think that somewhere there is public type "_operators"... And my _operators is private. I take a risk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to value-initialize the array:

```
Entity::Entity() : _operators() {}
//                           ^^
```

This works in C++03 and C++11.

Comment: +1 (obviously) And note, even now MS "warns" that this is an extension for C++0x3 and later (and then proceeds to do the right thing anyway, go figure). =P